# How to edit the Page?

Tags: wp-editor, wordpress.com-hosting

I've opened the WordPress page for editing, but I'm having trouble locating the content I want to edit. Is it possibly hidden, or could there be another issue? Can anyone assist me in resolving this problem? I apologize for any inconvenience, but my WordPress backend is in Japanese.

[image]